# Do we know when one of our posts is linked in another?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, linked-questions

I'm just curious to know if we can, in any way, know if one of our questions or answers are mentioned, maybe even linked, by another user?

Comment: You can always look at the "Linked" section next to your post. As far as being *notified* this would need to be opted-in to. I doubt John Saunders wants a notification about every NRE question.

Comment: You may also check this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/<post_id>

Comment: @BradleyDotNET IMHO, linked section shows the questions that're linked in that particular question and not the questions that link our question. I'm sorry for my messy sentence. For instance, if question A is linked in question B, A is going to appear in the linked section of B but B is not going to appear in A. Also, I do not mean a notification, but just like a tab that shows all the votes we cast, I was wondering if there's any indication for the linked posts.

Comment: @abn From everything I can see, it does go both ways (based on a quick test with the NRE canonical duplicate). The text when you click "See more linked questions" also supports this. Clicking that link, by the way, might be the closest you have. It certainly doesn't exist on the profile page (though you could feature request it, I doubt it would get a lot of traction).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thank you. That's just out of curiosity that I asked. No other intention.

Answer (score 2):

The linked section is bi-directional, it shows pages that are linked in your question/answer as well as other pages that link back to your question/answer.